# .htaccess: removing index.php from URL, force non-www and https

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have below code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In general index.php is not there in URL. But, when I tried to add www infront of URL. It comes up with index.php file.

e.g.

> https://example.com/settings/update_rates

After adding www infront of URL:

> https://example.com/index.php?/settings/update_rates

How can I remove `index.php` here.

Answer (score 1):

use this .htaccess

```
### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# Enforce SSL https://www. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

###
# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

[Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8503731/4595675)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the ideal .htaccess file for Codeigniter.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

After this goto /system/application/config/config.php
and then find following line

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

Make it as following

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Because you are using Apache mod_rewrite, the above will set your config file so that “index.php” will NOT show up as part of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You should give this try. I like to put my external redirects first. Also you can combine those rules by using your domain name. There is no point to using a wildcard unless you used this across many domains.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Then in your config.php file make sure you have already removed index.php.

Find below code:-

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Replace with the below code:-

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: It's same thing. When I try to open URL with `www` it appears with `index.php`

Comment: You're saying it's redirecting with Index.php? give me an example URL you are using.

Comment: It's redirecting to this URL: `https://example.com/index.php?/home` when I tried to add `www`.

Comment: You mean you are doing `www.example.com` and that's it? Are you sure you don't have any other redirects or a PHP redirect?

Comment: Let me give you actual URL. Just add `www` in front of this URL: `https://wiseremit.com/login/verify`

Comment: Let me know, what did you find? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have a valid cert so it's giving the cert error. Redirection is not going work properly until that is fixed.

Comment: It's temporary certificate. Just trust it in your browser. It's in development server, that's why.