# Redirecting to HTTPS returns error "too many redirects"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to force https via htaccess and am getting a "too many redirects" error.  Below is what I am using to try to accomplish this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this or why this doesn't seem to be working?

Edit:  I followed the answers from here [Force https://www. for Codeigniter in htaccess with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503663/force-https-www-for-codeigniter-in-htaccess-with-mod-rewrite)   which seems to be causing the redirect loop for me.  When I remove this part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The redirect loop goes away; however it isnt redirecting to https.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force https://www. for Codeigniter in htaccess with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503663/force-https-www-for-codeigniter-in-htaccess-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: I actually came across the post above prior to posting this.  I tried using the advice in that post, which is what seemed to cause the redirect loop.

Answer (score 17):

I can not say for sure if this is related to a (or some) hosting provider/s, but none of the solutions worked for me. Coz of restriction of hosting provider, I could not get the apache version except it was 2.x.

This is what did, maybe helpful to someone:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by RiggsFolly, there is an issue with the statement, but if that doesnt work, you could try force it in the head tag:

```
$use_sts = true;

// iis sets HTTPS to 'off' for non-SSL requests
if ($use_sts && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000');
} elseif ($use_sts) {
    header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 301);
    // we are in cleartext at the moment, prevent further execution and output
    die();
}``
```

Comment: If I can't get it to work in htaccess Im going to give this a shot.  Thanks.