# .htaccess CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have problems with htaccess on my project, when I use htaccess on the locale it runs fine and there is no problem, but when I upload it to the server it does not work.

I want my index.php to disappear, my domain is **sindangasih-server.com/receiving**.
receiving is the name of my project.

My htaccess is like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and my config configuration looks like this

```
$http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$newurl = str_replace("index.php","", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $newurl;

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

When I open sindangasih-server.com/receiving out writing like this.

> The requested URL /receiving/tiket/tampildatatiket was not found on this server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: none of which I tried to succeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force https://www. for Codeigniter in htaccess with mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503663/force-https-www-for-codeigniter-in-htaccess-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

Try using below config for the `base_url` :

```
$newurl = str_replace( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "" . $newurl;
```