# Mod rewrite from http:// to https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Hi i am new to mod rewrite htaccess, Can anyone help me to redirect each http:// request to https:// Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite all non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I have added it to my htaccess file but nothing happens.

Comment: @Death You make a valid point.

Comment: @h_a86 If nothing happens, chances are that your .htaccess isn't read. Make sure the AllowOverride directive in your Apache config is correct (i.e. All).