# Enabling SSL in Typo3

Tags: ssl, certificate, typo3

Hi Typo3 users out there,

I was wondering if Typo3 has native SSL support. The SSL certificate is allready installed on the server, but somehow I can't figure out how to enable SSL for all pages. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Dennis

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to do two things:

1. Use your vhost-configuration or .htaccess to redirect everything to a https-site. Here is how to do that: [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)
2. Configure TYPO3 to generate https-urls instead of http ones. You can do that by setting config.baseURL or config.absRefPrefix accordingly in TYPOScript. The latter setting is preferred, as it prevents some compatibility issues.

I hope that is everything that is needed, otherwiese please comment.

Comment: Accepting the answer might be due :)