# Force https for particluar URLs using Apache htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a website that I'd like to redirect any http:// traffic to a few specific URL's to https:// instead.

The URLs I'd like to redirect to are like this:

`http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/`

`http://domain.com/wp-admin/`

`http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php`

`http://domain.com/wp-login.php`

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite) as a guide is this correct?

```
# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# Pages to Apply
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-admin/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-login.php
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. Just some small corrctions:

```
# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/|wp-login\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also make sure these rules are right at top before any other WP rule.