# Smarty .htaccess rewrite (from nginx)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I want to add Apache .htaccess rules. This is from old server's nginx:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

    location / {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?demand=$1;
}
```

How to rewrite this? All I am getting now is index page and the rest of files are not found. I am really hoping to get some help here, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite part should simply be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?demand=$1 [L]
```

---

To force the use of https, add this *before* the above rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: And how can I include that with forcing to use https ?

Comment: Did you seen that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Here is converter from nginx to apache http://labs.gidix.de/nginx/