# Redirect to a specfic url http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I recently added SSL to my site. I want to write a redirect rule in .htaccess. When I am trying  to access http://the.mydomain.com/signup it wants to redirect to https://the.mydomain.com/envelop.

1. http://the.mydomain.com/login -> https://the.mydomain.com/login
2. http://the.mydomain.com/work ->  https://the.mydomain.com/work

I have checked lots of rules, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: you want if somone hits `http://the.mydomain.com/signup` he should automatically redirect to `https://the.mydomain.com/envelop` , i.e., http to https

Comment: oh its my mistake sorry , My requirement is if some one hits 1.http://the.mydomain.com/signup  it should automatically redirect to https://the.mydomain.com/signup  2. http://the.mydomain.com/login -> https://the.mydomain.com/login, 3.http://the.mydomain.com/work -> https://the.mydomain.com/work

Comment: All are same? Whats the difference?

Comment: I have checked below rules mentioned , but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Copy of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```