# How to force ssl with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

How to force SSL with htaccess
With this code i get a redirect error in chrome:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]  
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L] HTTPS_HOST ???
```

Thanks

Comment: don't do that. set up a separate vhost for your non-ssl version and put a an unconditional `RedirectPermanent` directive in there.

Comment: I only have webspace i don't have access to that files on server. Is there any other way to force ssl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Dosen't work , get a redirect error. (ERROR: the page shows a redirect)

Comment: Delete your cache or/and try from other browser

Comment: Dosen't work with cleared cache also not with firefox,same error, also with php version i get a redirect error

Comment: The site works when using https: // from browser url ?

Comment: Yes for sure :) but i use cloudflare, maybe this can be a problem with the shared ssl

Comment: Try with that `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$` instead of my 2nd line

Comment: Same thing, thanks anyway, i have contacted the support about this problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this code and its working fine

```
#Force SSL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```