# Domain won't go to https://example.com, when example.com is typed

Tags: php, ssl, fonts, opencart, font-awesome

I'm using an OpenCart 2 theme and my PHP skills aren't great.  My problem:

When I type example.com in, the SSL lock isn't displayed and my Font Awesome fonts do not display.  So the shopping cart icon just shows as a blank square.

However, if I click example.com's logo or manually type in https://example.com -- the lock displays and the fonts show up.  Everything works as it should.

How do I get the site to go straight to https://example.com when a user types in example.com?

I ran a test on the SSL and there aren't any problems with it, it shows everything sending as secure.

Comment: Sample of code that does not work?

Comment: I don't know what I would edit to do this.  This is an ecommerce site and I don't want any user being able to access it without https.  The domain automatically goes to http version, but the https works if you type it in https:// example.com or example.com/index.php but not when you just type in example.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vhost configuration, or in your `.htaccess` file, add an Apache redirect rule:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks I figured changing the .htaccess would do it but will it create any vulnerabilities security-wise?  Sorry I'm ignorant on this.

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Comment: @user3167513 no, it doesn't create any security problems. Anyways you could look at other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Comment: @user3167513: Unless your payment gateway callbacks are using HTTPS this is almost certainly going to mess them up

Comment: I copied this and it worked sometimes but now it is re-directing to just to: https:// www./

Any ideas?