# How to combine two .htaccess re-directs?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

In my MVC application, I'm directing all of my requests to my index.php file using an .htaccess file.  In addition, I'd like to enforce SSL.  Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite), I've added '#enforce https' code .  However, when I add the code to my .htaccess file, my browser complains that it will be unable to complete the request.  How can I have both rewrite rules in the same file?

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect to index.php as appropriate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

#enforce https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule that rewrites to `index.php` has a regex: `^(.+)$`, which matches everything. That includes anything you want to redirect. You need to have your redirect rules *before* your routing rules. Additionally, you need to make sure the nothing in index.php will redirect the browser back to non-SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On

#enforce https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect to index.php as appropriate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I actually had originally put my code in the order that you presented but neglected to check that nothing in index.php would direct back to non-SSL.