# htaccess redirect domain to https, subdomain with parameter to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I’m trying to do that:

Force the https for my main domain.

http or `https://www.domain.com`  -> `https://domain.com`
http or `https://domain.com`  -> `https://domain.com`

this is htaccess coding for domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

this is working fine

But not for subdomains

I want result as

```
https://www.domain.com/index.php?username=abc => http://abc.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/index.php?username=abc => http://abc.domain.com
```

And always removing the www and https to http.

but no idea how to write htaccess code for subdomain

Comment: this is for my domain htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
but i have no idea for http subdomain

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Joro Sorry, no, that question does _not_ answer this question.

Comment: @Joro this question is different in that he wants to enforce `https` for his primary domain *only*, while enforcing `http` for non-www subdomains.

Comment: @Ultimater yes you are right ,i need some help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will first check if you need to redirect to a subdomain based on the username parameter in the query string if requesting index.php. Then when rewritting to that subdomain, it will copy the entire querystring along with, but omitting the username parameter from it while preserving all other parameters.

The second part will check for your primary domain with or without www, then enforce https on it, if we didn't already decide to redirect to a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On

#match either the www subdomain or no subdomain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
#which request index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php
#and contain a username paramater
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)(?:^|&)username=([^&]+)(.*?)$
#then rewrite them to username.domain.com without the username parameter
  RewriteRule ^ http://%2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3 [R,QSA,L]

#match either the www subdomain or no subdomain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(?:domain\.com)$
#which was requested without https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#then redirect to https
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: -> thanks dude from the bottom of mah heart but a little problem ,its ok username=abc then abc.domain.com url is working but cannot fetch data using username=abc

Comment: If you want to include the username parameter, then use: `RewriteRule ^ http://%2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

Comment: i have tried but nothing happened url is working fine but cannot fetch data using username=abc
https://domain.com/index.php?username=abc page shows result abc
but abc.domain.com shows blank page

Comment: If you run `http://abc.domain.com/index.php?username=abc` directly, is it able to fetch data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90723/discussion-between-yupok-admin-and-ultimater).

Comment: a little problem arise