# How to set all link to https using php or .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to set all link to `https` using php or .htaccess ?

with this code

```
<?PHP
$path_image = "404.png";
?>
<img src="<?PHP echo $path_image; ?>">
```

when inspect elements it's show

```
<img src="404.png">
```

i want to change inspect view to

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/404.png">
```

How can i do that with php or .htaccess ?

Comment: htaccess cannot change your HTML source. It can only redirect/rewrite.

Comment: just add full path with image

Comment: example image tag from wikipedia not full path but redirect to https `<img alt="Sibelius in 1939" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg/120px-Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg" width="120" height="128" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg/180px-Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg/240px-Jean_Sibelius_1939.jpg 2x" data-file-width="335" data-file-height="357">`

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use .htaccess for force redirect with SSL

Note: htaccess can not change your HTML but it can redirect to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and if want to do with php than you have need to HTTP_HOST and after that manuly redirect to `https://hostname/$your_url`

Comment: when i use this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` it's not show green bat url but when i use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/style.css">` it's show green bar url. i want to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` and show green bar url how can i do that ?

Comment: as i have told you on my answer that you can not change on html, so you have to do it manualy. so add full https hostname before images, js, css after that it will show green bar.