# http:// to https:// redirect but something is overriding it back to http://

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my domain

- http://atc-logistics.ie

and

- http://www.atc-logistics.ie

to

- https://www.atc-logistics.ie

My hosting company gave me this code for the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^atc-logistics.ie [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.atc-logistics.ie/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and are insisting that there this is correct and something else is causing a redirect so it keeps rebounding back to http://atc-logistics.ie.  I can't see any other redirects and there are no redirect plugins (Wordpress).

Can anyone let me know if the redirect above is correct?  I am really struggling and the hosting company don't seem to be able to help!

Comment: please read [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/3536236)

Comment: And / or read up on [this StackOverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Thanks Martin, neither seemed to work, I just don't have the skills to troubleshoot them.  Looks like I might just have to keep bugging the hosting company.  I need to take a break from it - have been staring at .htaccess files for 4 hours - I might spontaneously combust.

Answer (score 0):

The `htaccess` redirect system I use is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And that works fine for me.

It checks if the host does *not* begin `www.` and then diverts to the `www.` address before *then* checking if the protocol is Secure and then if it is not forces redirect to the HTTPS, using the previously set `HOST` and `URI` address values.