# htaccess redirect not adding subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect `example.com/x/y/..` to `https://sub.example.com/x/y/..` with following rules in my htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The redirect however does not add the sub-path of the original URL to the new one. So instead of redirecting to `https://sub.example.com/x/y/..`, I'm just redirected to `https://sub.example.com`

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

In the present scenario that you have described, Apache is not able to pass on the remaining part of the URI. You need to use `%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` in the line for RewriteRule. Please refer this example: [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: I changed the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^ https://sub.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` but this does not work either. Then i tried to redirect first to https and then redirect to the location, but it just rewrites the hostname and forgets the rest.

Comment: O.k..did you try changing the `RewriteCond` line as well (as mentioned in the example)?