# having "https" at the beginning of URL without having to manually add it

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have a Comodo SSL certificate on my host plan, however when accesing my site from google, it sends me automatically to

http://example.com, Where the green lock doesn't appear.

If I manually add "https", like: https://example.com **it does show up!**

Is there a way to access my website always with the green lock showing up? instead of manually having to write it everytime?

Comment: Where do you host your website? Could you provide the name of hosting provider? Do you use a web proxy in front of your website?

Comment: I'm using DreamHost, no proxy

Comment: Can you edit .htaccess file ?

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily redirect to the https version of any page using rewrite rules/rewrite module of your web server (the exact way to do this depends on the webserver used). Ask your provider, this is a common case so there may even be a UI option in your console to do this.

Regarding google see this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67212/how-to-convince-google-to-list-https-version-of-website

It may also be good form to verify the protocol used to access the site in your authentication module and refuse authentication if the wrong protocol is used. Assuming web rules are used to redirect traffic this would to prevent leaking information due to a misconfiguration/bug.