# Laravel: .htaccess rule for redirecting to https not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, https

I'm developing a laravel app and I need to force HTTPS for it.i've tried many other solutions that i found on the internet but none of them worked.is it possible that my app some how ignores htaccess rules?

i've already tried these solutions:
[Laravel: how to force HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006146/laravel-how-to-force-https)

here's my httaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle redirect to Https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://foody.ir/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Everything to https, even https to https? You are missing condition, like `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`.

Comment: no I meant http to https .I tested the thing you said and other solutions in the link above but it still doesn't work.