# What would happen if you had two .HTACCESS files?

Tags: laravel

I would like to know what would happen if one has **two .HTACCESS files** in his/her hosting server.

I'm asking coz it seems I might be in that position. One already in hosting server and one again in laravel project. Could I possibly merge them?

I need honest answers please...

Comment: You cant have 2 .htacess files in the same directory.  You can have as many .htacess files on the same server as needed, one in each directory.  It's possible you can merge them, sure. Whether or not it causes issues depends on what is in the files I suppose - can you tell us more?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually the one on the remote server is to activate SSL and the other one is what's in Laravel project that will be uploaded to the remote server. How can they be merged into one single file?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to copy the SSL redirect stuff in the existing server .htaccess into your root laravel one.  Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006146/laravel-how-to-force-https

Comment: Whether you can simply "copy" the directives into a single file depends on the directives being copied. They might need changing to work at a different path depth. It depends.