# HTTPS with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I would like redirect all my URL to https. But it doesn't work. My .htaccess below. Could you help me please ? Something wrong ? Many thanks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.1.201
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.vilabea\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.vilabea.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/evenementiel$ https://www.vilabea.com/fr/les-seminaires [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/les-services$ https://www.vilabea.com/fr/le-restaurant [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/le-spa$ https://www.vilabea.com/fr/detente-et-bien-etre [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/el-spa$ https://www.vilabea.com/es/descanso-y-bienestar [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/index_new\.php$ https://www.vilabea.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: You could try being more descriptive than "it doesn't work", which would allow us to help you better.