# https redirect issue in opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

i have done secure security(https) in my website,if i open my website means it is showing like (http://www.kuberansilks.in/), but just one time refresh means https is taking i need if i open my site means it will open starting stage please help me (im using aws server).

my htaccess code below please check it.

```
 # SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kuberansilks.in/$1 [R,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kuberansilks\.in$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kuberansilks\.in [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kuberansilks.in/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.