# redirect http to https ubuntu/apache

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect to https, and fairly certain Ive written my htaccess correctly, but Its not redirecting for some reason. Any help is much appreciated.

#

```
RewriteEngine on


#### TJOSELFSTORAGE ####
RewriteCond %{ENV:CARET_ENV} live [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.tjoselfstorage.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((.*).(org|net|com)|(.*).(.*).(org|net|com)|[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tjoselfstorage.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteRule (^/images.*) https://www.tjoselfstorage.com? [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !__\^.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !resources

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !__\^.php
RewriteRule (.*) \__\^.php/$0 [L
```

]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: I tried adding that, but then I got stuck in a loop. Is there something on the bottom half of my htaccess file that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred method of redirecting http to https straight from Apache's documentation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```