# serving from http and https

Tags: wordpress, ssl

So if I look up worpress site http://example.com I get redirected to https://example.com because there is an SSL protocol implemented.

The problem starts when I need to authenticate to google webmaster. I have put google's .html file in my public html folder (my site's root folder).

If I hit http://example.com/googlefile.html, I got served.

If I hit http**s**://example.com/googlefile.html, I don't served.

How to ensure that all sites under my root directory got served through SSL?

Comment: Where is this website hosted? Do you manage the server software?

Comment: maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Comment: You are offtopic here, please use instead ServerFault. And you will certainly find answers there already to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)