# How to use ONLY .htaccess to force HTTPS on all pages on WordPress site hosted on 1and1

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have tirelessly tried to force HTTPS to my entire WordPress website after activating my free SSL certificate I received from 1and1 hosting so that all past HTTP links are redirected to HTTPS. I want to force HTTPS by modifying only the .htaccess file in the root of my web folder. I have tried multiple examples I have found on the web including:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

https://www.1and1.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/the-ten-best-htaccess-tricks/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# activate HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewirteCond %{Server_Port} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.tld/$1 [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

After trying all these methods of modifying the .htaccess file, none of them worked. I finally came across this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite) and put the PHP block of code in the functions.php file in my current theme folder. Here is the code:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}
```

This PHP code accomplished my goal of forcing all links to HTTPS. However, I desire to keep my code clean and leave it all in the .htaccess file for better organization and so I don't have to remember to add the PHP code to the functions.php file every time I change the theme of my WordPress website.

**Could anyone please explain how to accomplish forcing HTTPS by ONLY modifying the .htaccess file or explain where I may have gone wrong?**

The only active block of code in my .htaccess file is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

And I already changed my WordPress settings of "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to "https://example.com/".

Answer (score 0):

Situations such as `http` requests that must be redirected to `https` are better handled by the `Redirect` directive, according to [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect).  This directive would go into the server config file.

If you only have access to .htaccess then you should be able to use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried this out and it still does not work. When I visit a link to my site and change the schema from https to http, it stays at http and is not upgraded. I appreciate the suggestion however @justin-r

Comment: I only have access to the .htaccess file. I am using shared hosting.

Comment: You cannot edit a redirect. To modify a redirect, you must delete it, and then recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. It should have been:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I just had to do this on our Windows-based hosting package with them (now Ionos). I'm not sure why they require rewrites to be done with .htaccess rather than web.config. What I don't like is this puts in double slashes for some reason that I find annoying, and the standard ways to remove them don't work.