# How to manually change the addreses from http to HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, https, ssl-certificate

I have activated SSL certification on my new Wordpress website. But it is not showing that green lock in the browser. I installed Really Simple SSL plugin, but still nothing changed. I also tried to manually put this code inside the `.htaccess` file in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but even this didn't change anything. I still see "mix content warning" and the green lock is still not being showed. I want to manually change all the addresses but I don't know which files exactly should i work on? for example, where can i find my website's images to change their addresses from http to https? all the needed files, not only images.

I will appreciate if you share your experience with me to finally show that green lock for my website.

I activated my SSL two days ago, btw.

Comment: Hi Joseph, If you want to change the url of your site, then you can change the url in **admin** section (Dashboard) Under General settings..

Comment: If you are using static url for CSS, JS or images then you need to change the url manually in code to remove the "mix content warning".

Comment: 1. Clear cache
2. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

*** Back up your database and files before doing any of this! ***

You need to check 3 places and change the values if necessary:

1. Your site URL in WordPress settings
   You can update this value under `Settings > General` in WordPress admin (`yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-general.php`)
   This corresponds to 2 entries in the database. If you are familiar with the command-line, you can change them using `wp-cli`:
   `wp option update siteurl https://yoursite.com
   wp option update home https://yoursite.com`

This is the value WorPress uses to create your site's links (to a page, a post, an image etc.). But there might also be hard-coded http links in your database or in your theme, so:

2. Links in the WordPress database
   The easiest way is to export your database, find and replace the links and re-import it. There are also plugins that can do this for you, but if again, `wp-cli` makes this super easy:
   `wp db export mydb.sql`
   Open the file with your favorite editor, search for all occurrences of `http` and replace with `https` where appropriate.
   `wp db import mydb.sql`
3. Hardcoded links in your WordPress theme
   I use `ack-grep` for things like that. The following command searches for all occurrences of a pattern in the current directory, recursively (= it also searches in subdirectories):
   `ack -l "http:"`
   Then open each file with a text editor and change http links with https ones.