# Using https if not redirect to https

Tags: php, http, https, server

I am doing a project for my PHP class. It is required to check if the user is using https protocol if not, the user should be redirected to https. I found a this topic talking about it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite), and I implemented the code exactly at the beginning of my page. However, when I run the page, it tells me that my connection is not correct. I do not know if I implemented something wrong.

[image: example of what i am getting]

Comment: Your check seems to be fine, the problem is that the domain does not have a valid ssl certificate.

Comment: @jeroen how about if I want to redirect the user to https? I do not know if i am doing it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `advanced` -> `continue anyway`.

You will connect & hopefully your web server redirects you to the HTTPS version.

A lot of modern browsers are starting to do this to sites that don't have SSL chrome & firefox both warn iirc.

Or it's a self signed certificate in which case all modern browsers will warn you.

Comment: but should not the code redirect the user to https? In the advanced option, continue anyway is not available. Moreover, I am writing and running the code on a localhost.

Comment: you're probably using a self signed certificate then, in that case the browser will block it as well. Every browser is different, continue anyway may be under "learn more".