# Laravel remove public from url and force https in .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-6

How can I remove /public/ from url and auto force http to https?

my root .htaccess (I created it)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

public/.htaccess (by default laravel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it not works - no auto http to https redirect.

So I neet to combine removing public folder from url and forcing http to https using .htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 – Remove Public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Comment: Let's try to fix one problem after the other - where do you generate your URLs? Does your VHost configuration point to the root folder of your application, or to your public folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable rewrite_url with

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

restart your apache server

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Your site-enabled/000-default.conf

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourapp/public
```

May be you can use

```
RewriteBase "yourapp/public/"
```

or refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930/5321614) answer.

```
Rename server.php in your Laravel root folder to index.php
Copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder.
```

Comment: rewrite in installed

Comment: @Teretto document root is also set? or you may need to use rewrite base in htaccess.

Comment: I can't modify 000-default.conf in my hosting

Comment: @Teretto can you set RewriteBase in your htaccess, that may do the job.

Comment: @Teretto using this is effecting SSL configuration?

Comment: no auto redirect on hosting and local host too (in local I use https://laragon.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you've set your document root to be the root of the project. In your apache virtual host config you need to set the document root to be the public directory.

For example:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/yourproject/public
```

That way, public doesn't appear in the URL.

If you're using shared hosting you'll want to move the root of your project to above `public_html/`, delete `public_html`, then rename your `public` directory to `public_html`. You can then go and modify the bootstrap files to use this path. You could also symlink it.

Comment: my hosting do not allow to change apache/nginx settings. and I can't remove any default folders. I can use only htaccess

Comment: You can't delete `public_html`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this two line into your Public Folder `htaccess` file

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule .* https://yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Full Code of your `public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule .* https://yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in .htaccess file of root directory of domain for removing 'public :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And for redirecting to https from http add following lines at the top in .htaccess file located in public directory of laravel project.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} your_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.your_domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```