# Switch http to https

Tags: php, apache, https, ssl-certificate

I have a PHP script which receives user and pass as a URL parameter and stores this in a database. 
In order to use this script I have to access

```
http://ipadress/script.php?user=testuser&pass=1234
```

that's the IP address of a Linux machine.

What changes should I make in order to be able to change from http to https? I have to use SLL certificates or is there a solution which allow me to do this from my PHP script?

Can you offer me some hints, please ?

Comment: The server needs to have SSL enabled. Then from your PHP script you can just change `http://` to `https://` in order to access the URL.

Comment: See if this helps: http://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_apache.html. I don't think you can do anything from your PHP script if the server itself is not running SSL.

Comment: Additionally, SSL Certificate itself is optional. You can have SSL enabled without a certificate.

Comment: You will need an SSL certificate and then you can rewrite all requests in the htaccess, https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html.. more http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865143/what-do-i-have-to-code-to-use-https

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps!

```
    $redirect= false;
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $redirect= true;
    } else {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on")
            $redirect= true;
    }
    if ($redirect) {
        $url = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: ".$url); 
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: I corrected this to fix a variable that was not renamed and changed the redirect to make actual header calls. This is more correct now as far as redirecting someone from http to https. I also added a `301 Moved Permanently` header which will help with stuff like SEO.